# Cargar un array en select - Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

Tengo un formulario en un documento `HTML` con un campo `select` donde cargo varias provincias.
¿Es correcta esta forma de cargar las provincias en el Select? Me da error.

```
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
    <option value="cargar_provincias();">Seleccione una Provincia...
</select>

function cargar_provincias(){
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    var provincia = document.getElementById("provincia");
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){ 
        provincia.options[i] = new option(array[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: Podrias poner el error que te aparece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para invocar una función desde un *tag* ***HTML*** debes hacerlo dentro de un **evento** (`onClick="..."`, `onFocus="..."`, etc.). Si dicha función se debe ejecutar una sola vez te recomiendo colocarla en el evento `onLoad="..."` del *tag* `<body>`.

> **NOTA:**
> No necesariamente tienes que usar `id` para accesar un elemento en el **DOM**, puedes también hacerlo a través de la propiedad [name](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp): `document.getElementsByName("...")[0]`, de esta forma te ahorras codigo al escribir.
>
> Adicionalmente te dejo un ejemplo de:
> como agregar opciones a un *tag **HTML*** `<select>` desde un *array*.
>
> Y también es útil saber como: **ordenar el array alfabeticamente**.

Ejemplo:

```js
//Codigo a Ejecutar al Cargar la Pagina
function myOnLoad() {
 cargar_provincias()
}

// funcion para Cargar Provincias al campo <select>
function cargar_provincias() {
 var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];

 // Ordena el Array Alfabeticamente, es muy facil ;)):
 array.sort();

 addOptions("provincia", array);
}

// Rutina para agregar opciones a un <select>
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
 var select = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];

 for (value in array) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = array[value];
  select.add(option);
 }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="myOnLoad()">
 <select name="provincia">
  <option>Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
 </select>
</body>
```

> **EDITADO:**
> Aqui les dejo otro ejemplo utilizando como fuente de los datos provenientes de un elemento **JSON** en lugar de un **array**

```js
//Codigo a Ejecutar al Cargar la Pagina
function myOnLoad() {
 cargar_provincias()
}

// funcion para Cargar Provincias al campo <select>
function cargar_provincias() {
 var json = {"Cantabria":"", "Asturias":"", "Galicia":"", "Andalucia":"", "Extremadura":""};

 addOptions("provincia", json);
}

// Rutina para agregar opciones a un <select>
function addOptions(domElement, json) {
 var select = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];

 Object.keys(json).forEach(function(elm) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = elm;
  select.add(option);
 })
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="myOnLoad()">
 <select name="provincia">
  <option>Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
 </select>
</body>
```

Espero este ejemplo sea una buena ilustración del: **como hacerlo**, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: Hola @fwBasic, podria modificar el codigo para cargar el array mediante un JSON, por ejemplo [Paises](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/master/countries.json), se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Estimado @Nor, he modificado la respuesta añadiendo otro ejemplo que utiliza como fuente de datos un JSON en lugar de un array sin embargo te comento que los datos que tu expones en "Paises" se componen de un array que contiene JSON como elementos, en cuyo caso solo tendrias que agregar el elemento ".nombre" en el ejemplo 1 al momento de recorrer el array reemplazando por: `option.text = array[value].nombre;` y ya tienes el problema solucionado  ;))...

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te recomiendo es que ejecutes la función que se encargará de crear tus **elementos `{opciones}`** una vez el **documento esté listo**, te pongo el ejemplo basándome en tu código y usando un poco de **jQuery**:

> **EDIT**: como me has dicho que no puedes usar **jQuery** aquí te dejo un
>   ejemplo con puro **JavaScript**:

```js
function cargar() {
    var provincias = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"]; //Tu array de provincias
    var select = document.getElementById("provincias"); //Seleccionamos el select
    
    for(var i=0; i < provincias.length; i++){ 
        var option = document.createElement("option"); //Creamos la opcion
        option.innerHTML = provincias[i]; //Metemos el texto en la opción
        select.appendChild(option); //Metemos la opción en el select
    }
}
cargar();
```

```html
<select id="provincias"></select>
```

> El ejemplo usando jQuery:

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="provincias"></select>
```

**JavaScript + jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var provincias = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];

    for(var i=0; i < provincias.length; i++){ 
        var option = document.createElement("option"); //Creas el elemento opción
        $(option).html(provincias[i]); //Escribes en él el nombre de la provincia
        $(option).appendTo("#provincias"); //Lo metes en el select con id provincias
    }
});
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda :)

Comment: podrias ponerlo de tal forma que el ejemplo se reproduzca utilizando el editor de la pagina?

Comment: El problema es que en este ejercicio sólo se puede utilizar Javascript, nada de jQuery.

Comment: @omaza1990 Ya actualicé la respuesta, suerte!

Answer (score 3):

un saludo y suerte .

```
<select name="provincia" id="provincia"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cargar_provincias()
        {
            var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
            for(var i in array)
            { 
                document.getElementById("provincia").innerHTML += "<option value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>"; 

            }
    }

    cargar_provincias();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .center-content {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .pad-2 {
            padding: 2%;
        }
        .pad-10 {
            padding: 10%;
        }
        .wmx-30 {
            max-width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        // Aux. func.
        // Wrap for document.querySelector()
        function qs(nodeSelector, node = null) // js node | null
        {
            node = (node !== null && node.nodeType !== 1) ? null : node;

            return (node || document).querySelector(nodeSelector);
        }

        // Func to populate a select
        function loadSelector(selectNode, arrData) // void
        {
            console.log('@loadSelector');
            if (!selectNode || selectNode.nodeType !== 1) {
                console.error('No se ha cargado el nodo "select"');
                return;
            }
            selectNode = resetSelector(selectNode);

            for (let i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                const fakeRegionValue = i + 1;
                const regionName = arrData[i];

                const optionNode = composeOption(fakeRegionValue, regionName);
                selectNode.appendChild(optionNode);
            }

            function composeOption(optionValue, optionText) // js node
            {
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                const optionContent = document.createTextNode(optionText);

                option.appendChild(optionContent);
                option.setAttribute('value', optionValue);

                return option;
            }

            function resetSelector(selectNode) // js node
            {
                const firstOption = qs('option', selectNode);
                selectNode.innerHTML = null;
                selectNode.appendChild(firstOption);

                return selectNode;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="pad-10 center-content">
    <label for="provincia">Seleccione una Provincia</label>
    <select name="provincia" id="provincia" class="pad-2 wmx-30">
        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
    </select>

    <script>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Script functions

        function loadOnNaturalOrder(selectNode, arrData) // void
        {
            console.log('@loadOnNaturalOrder');

            loadSelector(selectNode, arrData);
        }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Run script

        const arrData = [
            "Cantabria",
            "Asturias",
            "Galicia",
            "Andalucia",
            "Extremadura"
        ];

        const selectNode = qs('select#provincia');

        window.onload = () => {
            loadOnNaturalOrder(selectNode, arrData);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Yo partiría de la ***estructura base HTML***: el `select` vacío o bien con el primer `option`, que no suele tener un contenido "útil" mas allá de indicar la acción a realizar. He añadido un `label` para que la estructura HTML sea "correcta".

Hay un primer bloque `<script>` con funciones auxiliares, que pueden ***reutilizarse*** para un propósito determinado cuando sea necesario. Las he puesto separadas del *script principal* si bien su posición en la página no importa demasiado.

El *script principal* si requiere una posición determinada, en este caso debe situarse siempre por debajo del `select` ya que de otra forma la línea:

```
const selectNode = qs('select#provincia');
```

Trataría de cargar un elemento de la página que aun no se encuentra en el documento.

En cuanto al código, al cargar la ventana se ejecuta la function que rellena el selector con el array de strings que se le pase en el orden en que están:

```
window.onload = () => {
    loadOnNaturalOrder(selectNode, arrData);
}
```

lo que hace indirectamente la function auxiliar `loadSelector(selectNode, arrData);`

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta me sirvio mucho para lograr una idea. Ahora me ocurre un problema que solo puedo llamar a esa funcion una sola vez en un select.
Yo tengo un formulario donde hay que seleccionar que club va a ganar, por lo que uso el select permanentemente, pero me deja usarlo solo una vez.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/327101)