# Llenar un formulario con datos de un json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, dom

Hola buenas tardes comunidad, tengo una duda, es posible llenar un formulario mediante un json.

Por ejemplo tengo una variable asi:

```
var json={'id':1,'nombre':'Carlos Cauich'};
```

y llenar este formulario con mi JSON:

```
<form><input type="text" name="id"><input type="text" name="name"></form>
```

Comment: Esto ya ha sido respondido anteriormente, podrías revisar [Esta Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/69844/91499), aqui se llena un Select pero la lógica es la misma para otro elemento de un elemento `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Claro con Js es Sencillo:

Te dejo un Ejemplo

```js
var json={'id':1,'nombre':'Carlos Cauich'};
document.getElementById("id").value=json["id"];
document.getElementById("name").value=json["nombre"];
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</form>
```

PD: le pude id a los inputs para colocar sus valores del JSON

Answer (score 0):

Pues claro que sí. Con Javascript.

Necesitarás asignar etiquetas id a los elementos del formulario a los que quieres asignar valor:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</form>
```

Y asignarles valor es fácil con Javascript puro:

```
document.getElementById('id').value = json.id;
document.getElementById('name').value = json.name;
```

O, con jQuery:

```
$('#id').val(json.id);
$('#name').val(json.name);
```

Si estás preguntando esto es que quizá te falta un poco de formación básica, al menos sobre Javascript. ¡Ánimo!