# Tengo un objeto con datos de Departamentos y Localidades y quiero recorrerlos para asignar datos a un select en javascript

Tags: html5, formularios, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y dado el siguiente objeto quisiera recorrerlos de alguna manera para los datos se introduzcan en un select como options.

```
  var dptosLocs = {
  "Artigas":["Artigas","Bella Unión"],
  "Canelones":["Canelones","Santa Lucía"],
  "Montevideo":["Montevideo"],
  "Salto":["Salto","Daymán","Arapey"]
   };
```

En un select voy a tener las option "Artigas", "Montevideo", "Canelones" y "Salto". Cuando elijo un Departamento en el primer select, otro select deberia mostrarme como opciones las localidades correspondientes.

El codigo html que estoy probando es basico solo es un form con un select. El segundo select deberia crearlo con Javascript o tal vez ambos select podrian crearse con Javascript directamente??

```
  <form>
     <select></select>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Tal vez [estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69836/cargar-un-array-en-select-javascript) te pueden orientar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Los podrías crear ambos desde `Javascript` al obtener las llaves en una variable para el `select1` y los valores habría que "aplanarlos" (`Flatten`) en un arreglo de una dimensión para el `select2`.

Ejemplo:

```js
 var dptosLocs = {
  "Artigas":["Artigas","Bella Unión"],
  "Canelones":["Canelones","Santa Lucía"],
  "Montevideo":["Montevideo"],
  "Salto":["Salto","Daymán","Arapey"]
   };

// Obtener llaves del arreglo
var select1_val = Object.keys(dptosLocs);

// Obtener los valores de cada índice en un solo arreglo
var select2_val = Object.values(dptosLocs).flat();

var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");

for(var i = 0; i < select1_val.length; i++) {
    var opt = select1_val[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select1.appendChild(el);
}

for(var i = 0; i < select2_val.length; i++) {
    var opt = select2_val[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select2.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
 <form id="formulario">
     <select id="select1"></select>
     <select id="select2"></select>
  </form>
```

Esto es un ejemplo sencillo, si desearas que los valores del `select2` dependieran de lo seleccionado en el `select1` habría que elegir únicamente los valores de la llave correspondiente antes de rellenar las opciones del `select2`.

Comment: Excelente es justo lo que busco